# When to set a constant value? Inside a class or during initialisation?

Tags: .net

I am new with OOP and have a construction question.

I have a class called Person with the subclasses (StrongPerson, CrazyPerson etc.). The Person class has many properties one of them is Property Strength.

```
Public Class Person
private m_Strength as integer
Protected Property Strength() as Integer
End Class

Public Class StrongPerson
Inherits Person
...

End Class
```

Every Subclass has his own Strengthvalue. E.g. StrongPerson has a value of 10. I see two possibilities of coding that. Either I set the 10 in the Subclass (but I dont know how to do this) or I set the 10 during initialisation. What is the common or prefered way of coding that?

Comment: I would do it in the constructor of the subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Property Strength()` is a property of the superclass for which subclasses must supply value, you have at least two valid approaches to implementing this:

- Making a protected constructor that takes the value of `strength`, and storing it in `m_Strength`
- Making the getter of the property abstract, and dropping the `m_Strength` member. This would force the `Person` class to be abstract. All subclasses would need to provide their own implementation of the getter for the `Strength` property, returning their own constants.

You could also make `m_Strength` protected, and set it inside constructors of subclasses. This choice is very fragile, because programmers who implement subclasses may forget to set the strength, and the compiler wouldn't be able to help them spot this problem. This approach should be restricted to situations when `m_Strength` has a very good default that applies most of the time.

Comment: Thank you for this very instructive answer!

Answer (score 0):

If the class itself decides what its property value to be, then it is not supposed to have a `setter`. You can use a virtual computed property, then you can override it in subclasses.

```
class Person
{
    protected virtual int Strength //can be abstract 
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }
}

class StrongPerson : Person
{
    protected override int Strength
    {
        get { return 10; }
    }
}

class WeakPerson : Person
{
    protected override int Strength
    {
        get { return 2; }
    }
}
```

For VB.Net version you can use this [online converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)